# KnockoutJS async

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

Can anyone tell me the best way to do three seperate get requests from knockout to .net WebAPI to bind observable arrays in the following code?  Firebug shows the load times as a few ms but it is actually taking a few seconds.

I was hoping to get some guidance before looking at any javascript async.

```
   $(function () { 
        var model = new viewModel();
        model.todayTimes([]); 
        model.zones([]);
        model.dayTypes([]);

        $.get('../api/Zone', function (data) {
        model.zones(data);

        });

         $.get('../api/DayType', function (data) {
        model.dayTypes(data);

        });

        $.get('../api/TemplateTime/?dayTypeId='+model.dayType(), function (data) { 
            model.todayTimes(data); 
            ko.applyBindings(model); 
        });
```

EDIT

```
function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.dayType = ko.observable(1);
         self.todayTimes = ko.observableArray([]);
         self.dayTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
         self.zones = ko.observableArray([]);

//other code

  $.getJSON("/api/Zone", function(data) {
    self.zones(data);


    $.getJSON("/api/DayType", function(data) {
    self.dayTypes(data);
    }); 

       $.getJSON('../api/TemplateTime/?dayTypeId=1', function (data) { 
            self.todayTimes(data); 
        }); 

}
  $(function () { 
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());           
      });
```

Comment: I encourage you to check out the knockout tutorials, they cover this topic, as well as basic usage (like how to make observables for binding): http://learn.knockoutjs.com

Comment: Tyrsius, I have been through them and will again now but I can't see where he is binding multiple observablearrays initially like I am

Comment: You aren't binding any observables arrays. You aren't making any observables at all. This code shows a significant knowledge gap in how to use knockout, beyond just the question you are asking. The final tutorial covers this usage case.

Comment: I was missing some code, I've also changed the way I am getting the data after going through some tutorials again.  Is this back on track or am I still a bit away from the concepts.

Comment: Man, that's a big improvement for 20 minutes! Let me put an answer together for your.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept / upvote in the morning, going to bed!

Comment: Paul, I think your example highlights something more important that is hard with knockout - coordinating separate asynchronous bindings.  Let's say for example you were rendering a template that required all three of those observable arrays and the ajax requests were to three separate servers.  I am currently googling around for "async knockout" and "recursive async knockout" and am finding some good resources.  Hope those help you too.  By the way, you should probably remove the original code from your question as it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I would start off by asking a if they need to be 3 calls, because making three seperate ajax requests on page load is enormously wasteful. There are almost certainly better ways to do this. Also, is this a one time get, or does it need to be re-usable?

If it's a one time get, I have to wonder why it is happening at all. This data should be collected by the server and sent down with the initial page request. This is the optimal path. How this is done depends on your server stack, but all of them support model-serialization to JSON, which you can dump right into your viewmodel during consruction.

If it needs to be re-usable (which is the only reason to make these ajax requests), then do they really need to be 3 seperate calls? They look like they are related, and all the data *could* potentially be requested at once. Combining this into something reusable might look like this:

```
var ViewModel = function(initialData) {
    var self = this;
    self.dayType = ko.observable(initialData.dayType || []);
    self.todayTimes = ko.observableArray(initialData.todayTimes || []);
    self.dayTypes = ko.observableArray(initialData.dayTypes || []);
    self.zones = ko.observableArray(initialData.zones || []);

    self.getData = function() {
        $.getJSON("/api/timeInfo", function(data) {
            self.todayTimes(data.todayTimes || self.todayTimes()));
            self.dayTypes(data.dayTypes || self.dayTypes()));
            self.zones(data.zones || self.zones()));
        };
    };
};
```

If they really need to be 3 seperate calls, you can split `getData` up, but again, only do this if they are *truly independent* calls. If you do split them, I would follow the pattern of making them functions on the viewmodel. This allows them to be called externally, and bound to by the view. Reusable.

Comment: Thanks, I did think about one call but wasn't sure how I could bind to sub json elements.  I will figure it out now with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Tyrsius that you need to pack the three requests into one single "wrapper API call" to overcome the latency problem.

I propose to elaborate the above view model so it can be even more reusable in both inline data / ajax request data:

```
function ViewModel(initialData) {
  // setup properties
  this.dayType = ko.observable();
  this.todayTimes = ko.observable();
  this.dayTypes = ko.observable();
  this.zones = ko.observable();

  if (initialData) {
    this.update(initialData);
  }
}

ViewModel.prototype.update = function(data) {
  data.todayTimes && this.todayTimes(data.todayTimes);
  data.dayTypes && this.dayTypes(data.dayTypes);
  data.zones && this.zones(data.zones);
};

ViewModel.prototype.load = function() {
  $.getJSON('/api/timeInfo', this.update.bind(this));
};
```

Anyway **in the unfortunate case you are not able to create the wrapper API endpoint** but you want to update the UI when all the necessary data are loaded then you can't help yourself but going with an async support.

jQuery provides you with the [deferred objects API](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) but there is also the Async library which provides the [parallel tasks API](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) which seems to me to solve your problem.